# Twython. Issues authenticating [Twitter API returned a 401]

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, oauth, twython

So here is my code so far, I'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong. 
OAUTH_TOKEN and OAUTH_TOKEN_SECERT print out fine, it's just when it comes to displaying the timeline it seems to of not worked.

```
def login():

    APP_KEY = 'xxxxxx'
    APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxx'

    log = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
    auth = log.get_authentication_tokens()
    webbrowser.open(auth['auth_url'], new=2, autoraise=True)
    print 'If your web browser did not open go to this url: ' + auth['auth_url']
    oauthverify = int(input('Please enter the PIN displayed: '))
    print auth['oauth_token']
    print auth['oauth_token_secret']
    twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, auth['oauth_token'], auth['oauth_token_secret'])
    final = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(oauthverify)

    OAUTH_TOKEN = final['oauth_token']
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECERT = final['oauth_token_secret']

    print OAUTH_TOKEN
    print OAUTH_TOKEN_SECERT

    print twitter.get_home_timeline()
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: is oauthverify suppossed to be an int?
Docs:

__oauth_verifier = request.GET['oauth_verifier']__